# Redux saga Payload

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-saga

not really certain about my request
but I'm kind of new to redux saga freshly from redux it self.
on redux when I want to dispatch and action I'll do that by dispatching the action object with the type and the payload if needed.

now it quite same using redux saga but I'm worried about how i could get hold of my payload in my saga middleware,or saga watchers.Cause if I'm to carry out a fetch request base on the payload I dispatch my action with how will I get hold of the payload

nothing never really had any idea on how to go about it

Comment: The action is given as an argument to the saga so it should not cause you any trouble

Comment: Just to make sure you are not falling prey to an old tutorial: You are generally aware that we nowadays recommend other, less complicated options than redux-saga for 97% of Redux apps? See https://redux.js.org/usage/side-effects-approaches
Also, just to make sure: you are using the modern Redux style with `createSlice` instead of the pre-2019 legacy style with ACTION_TYPES, switch..case reducers, immutable reducer logic etc.? Unfortunately many tutorials still show off that old style. In doubt, you can read more about modern Redux here: https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today